# How should I fix my for loop code for summing a range?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, sum, range

```
function needToAdd(start, end) {
   for(var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    start += i;
}
return start
};

console.log(needToAdd(1, 10));
// 56
```

Hey guys, I just want to find out how I can sum the ranges using a for loop in javascript. What I have here works, but it gives me 56, instead of 55. What should I change in start += i to make it so that it will give me the sum of (1 + 2 + 3... + 10) instead of ( 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4.... + 10)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your code to following

```
function needToAdd(start, end) {
   for(var i = start+1; i <= end; i++) {
    start += i;
}
return start
}
```

**Note**: Let us say your start and end is 1. So, in this case, your loop would have executed once and have added 1 to start and would have updated it to 2. Hence, you have to execute your loop from 1 next to start.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in loop you initialized `i = start` in the beginning and you stored the result as `start += i`. Hence your `actual result` is `expected + start`.

Solution 1: Use `temp` variable for result and return `temp`.

```js
var sumInRange = function(a, b) {
  var i = t = b;
  while (a <= --i) t += i;
  return t;
};

alert(sumInRange(1, 5));
alert(sumInRange(1, 10));
```

Solution 2: Without `temp` variable

```js
var sumInRange = function(a, b) {
  if (a === b) return a;
  return b + sumInRange(a, b - 1);
};

alert(sumInRange(1, 5));
alert(sumInRange(1, 10));
```